# modal?.ShowAsync() throwing an error when called in OnInitializedAsync() to generate a Modal

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to open a Modal on the initialization of a blazor page. I have used below code to generate the Modal. When I am using OnClick function it is being pop-up correctly but when the same function is being called inside OnInitializedAsync() it is throwing an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**ShowModal.razor**

```
<Modal @ref="modal" Title="Modal title">
    <BodyTemplate>
        @sMessage
    </BodyTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <Button Color="ButtonColor.Secondary" @onclick="OnHideModalClick">Close</Button>
    </FooterTemplate>
</Modal>

@*  <Button Color="ButtonColor.Primary" @onclick="OnShowModalClick">Show Modal</Button>  *@

@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    public string sMessage { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public bool bShowModal { get; set; } = false;


    private Modal modal;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await OnShowModalClick();
    }

    private async Task OnShowModalClick()
    {
        await modal?.ShowAsync();
    }
    private async Task OnHideModalClick()
    {
        await modal?.HideAsync();
    }
}
```

```
ListMail.razor


<CascadingValue  Value="@sMessageModal">
    <ShowModal></ShowModal>
</CascadingValue>
```

I am expecting to pop Modal using modal?.ShowAsync() on the initialization of the blazor page.[image] I have attached image of the error

Comment: I haven't test  it out but I'm afraid it's related to [lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0), have you tried to use `OnAfterRenderAsync` instead of `OnInitializedAsync`?

Comment: I test in my side and I shared my test result below. Using `OnAfterRenderAsync ` can solve your issue. Pls correct  me if I misunderstood your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I can reproduce your issue in my sample using Blazor.Bootstrap Modal.  Like you can see, this is resulting from the null value for `modal` parameter.

[image]

In short, when we call `OnInitializedAsync`, the parameter hasn't been initialized, so we need call the `OnShowModalClick` method later than `OnInitiaized`. Here I had a test with `OnAfterRenderAsync` and it worked well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you try to call `ShowAsync`, your page hasn't yet rendered, so the modal dialog doesn't exist, and a reference to it hasn't been assigned.

Tiny Wang's answer is perfectly valid, but you can also solve the problem by forcing the component to render in `OnInitializedAsync` before you call `ShowAsync`.

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        // Component will render here
        await OnShowModalClick();
    }
```